# Should I write "wouldn't know if you did" or "wouldn't know if you had" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> Speaker A: "I don't sleepwalk."
>
> Speaker B: "You wouldn't know if you **did/had**."
>
> Speaker A: "But you would."
>
> Speaker B: "Not if I was asleep."

Should it be **did** or **had**? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Kman3 said in their answer, which one you need to use is reliant on what is being implied.

> "You wouldn't know if you **had *sleepwalked***"

Here, the [Past Perfect](http://www.englishtenses.com/tenses/past_perfect) indicates the sleepwalking has been completed already and was finished before a second past action began.

vs

> "You wouldn't know if you **did sleepwalk**"

Meanwhile, the [Past Simple](http://www.englishtenses.com/tenses/past_simple) indicates the sleepwalking happened at a specific time in the past and it could have been for either a long or short timespan.

---

Since you used "don't" in the first sentence rather than "didn't", keeping it in the *Present Simple* tense could clarify things for readers further. This works if the conversation discusses something that happens frequently, happens generally, or is a narrative.

> A: You don't sleepwalk.
>
> B: I wouldn't know if I do [sleepwalk].
>
> A: But you would [know].
>
> B: Not if I were asleep.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [auxiliary verb](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/auxiliary-verbs) *did*, emphasizing the general action of sleepwalking.

> You wouldn't know if you sleepwalk.
>
> You wouldn't know if you ***did*** [sleepwalk].

*Had* is the [past perfect](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-perfect/),  and requires the past participle *sleepwalked*. If Speaker A was referring to a past event of sleepwalking rather than sleepwalking itself, this would  be better.

> I **didn't** sleepwalk.
>
> You wouldn't know if you **had** [sleepwalked].